# Using variables returned in object in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Im new to ruby and need to know how to easily display the specific variables in this returned response below.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

### response

```
[#<Fedex::Rate:0x007fb9320ba7f0 @service_type="FEDEX_GROUND", 
  @rate_type="PAYOR_ACCOUNT_PACKAGE", @rate_zone="4", @total_billing_weight="6.0 LB", 
  @total_freight_discounts={:currency=>"USD", :amount=>"2.75"}, @total_net_charge="6.84", 
  @total_taxes="0.0", @total_net_freight="6.42", @total_surcharges="0.42", 
  @total_base_charge="9.17", @total_net_fedex_charge=nil, @total_rebates="0.0">]
```

Comment: what values you want to display ?

Comment: We can't help you based on the code you've posted. You need to figure out what public methods the `Fedex::Rate` class exposes.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Im just trying to display any of the @'s.

Comment: check if any getter method exist like `#rate_type` for the instances of the class `Fedex::Rate`..

Comment: Do you have access to the source code of this object? If so paste that. It'll either be self explanatory or folks here can help you with code in front of them.

Comment: https://github.com/jazminschroeder/fedex?

Comment: @Stefan Yes this is the lib im using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/jazminschroeder/fedex), you call it this way:

```
rate = fedex.rate(:shipper=>shipper,
                  :recipient => recipient,
                  :packages => packages,
                  :service_type => "FEDEX_GROUND",
                  :shipping_options => shipping_options)
```

and then any of the instance variables (the `@` variables) can be retrieved via an accessor:

```
puts rate.total_net_charge
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, appreciate the response. Im receiving a `NoMethodError` for `total_net_charge` by doing it this way. Any ideas?

Comment: It's not sufficient to know that it's a `NoMethodError`, you have to know what object it is being sent to. Please note the object in the error message.

Comment: The returned response is `undefined method `total_net_charge' for #<Array:0x007fc8db3499b8> (NoMethodError)`

Comment: For some reason, your response is being wrapped in an Array. I'd like to see your calling code. Does it match the examples on the gem's documentation page? Try `rate.first.total_net_charge` instead.

Comment: So if i had `first` to the call, it works!!! Thank you Mark. And yes it matches exactly what the doc states.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the response is an array with one object of type Fedex::Rate.  As mentioned by others, you should read the docs to see what Fedex::Rate exposes as methods.  To programatically see the methods Fedex::Rate exposes you could use:

```
rate = response.first
puts rate.methods
```

Alternatively if you want to read the variables from the object (which is probably a bad idea), you could use:

```
rate.instance_variable_get('@total_freight_discounts')
```

Comment: Thanks @Pierre Pretorius! The returned methods are in my above updated description.

Comment: @JaisonBrooks That looks like a stacktrace, not a method list.